# store multiple value with same input name in sql

Tags: php

I need to insert the value of form into the data table.

here is my form for taking a test.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    1<input type="text" name="answer">
    3<input type="text" name="answer">
    5<input type="text" name="answer">
    7<input type="text" name="answer">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

how to store this all answer in one field of the data table

i have tried this code but  its not storing all value

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $answer = json_encode($_POST['answer']);
    $query = "INSERT INTO `test` (`answer`) VALUES ('$answer')";
    mysqli_query($con, $query);

    if (mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
        echo "inserted ";   
    } else {
        echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
```

Comment: name the field `answer[]` then you can access as an array in php. How you process that array in PHP is up to you of course

Comment: So what sort of values does it store and what sort of values does it not store?

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your HTML code to this.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    1<input type="text" name="answer[]">
    3<input type="text" name="answer[]">
    5<input type="text" name="answer[]">
    7<input type="text" name="answer[]">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

When you submit the form the `$_POST['answer']` would look something like this

```
Array
(
    [answer] => Array
        (
            [0] => first answer
            [1] => second answer
            [2] => third answer
            [3] => fourth answer
        )

)
```

Above is a printout of `$_POST` variable like so `print_r($_POST)`

Now you can easily get all the `answer` inputs inside PHP and have it converted to json like so

```php
$answer = json_encode($_POST['answer']);
```

However since you are saving this inside mysql I would suggest using `serialize()` instead of `json_encode()`. Please read about `serialize()` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Do you have any explanation why you would suggest serialize instead of json? If you serialize the the value, you have made the data in the database language specific. If anything, I would argue that they should normalize their database instead of storing multiple values in one column.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson you are correct and I agree with you. I suggested `serialize()` because it is faster and it's something I would use if I was building something like this. If this data is going places I would suggest json_encode for portability. Great question, thank you.

Comment: _"I suggested serialize() because it is faster"_ - Actually, serialize and unserialize (which needs to be taken into consideration) are pretty slow so I wouldn't automatically agree with that.

Comment: It's only a suggestion, nobody actually needs to take my word for it. I've just found it to be more faster. This is a great topic to open for a discussions I'm sure there would be many mixed answers regarding this. Thank you for bringing it up @MagnusEriksson